# What does "operate on one's time" mean?

Tags: meaning

Here is the context:

> When you are on stage and make people **operate** just for a few seconds **on** your time while they pay rapt attention waiting for you to say something, it creates an air of anticipation.

I have checked all the meaning of *operate*, but only have a vague idea of what that could mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word is being used very broadly and vaguely there; the meaning is "to function".

The "rapt" audience forgets themselves and awaits your words.  You decide when to speak, in your own good time, which creates "an air of anticipation", that is, puts the audience on the edges of their seats, as the saying goes.

The person on stage "sets the tempo".

P.S. The phrase **on my time** means "according to what suits my schedule".

> I can help you move into a new apartment this weekend, but it will have to be on my time. I have some prior obligations.

That would be spoken "on MY time", the word **my** receiving emphasis.  So **on *your* time** in this particular context would be "according to your desired  pace or timing".

Comment: I like your simplification: The person on stage "sets the tempo" but ... is correct the use of "operate/function on your time"? It sounds very awkward to my foreign ears if I try to translate it. Is it a common expression to function on somebody's time?

Comment: There is a phrase **to operate on a schedule** which I think might lie behind this mechanistic phrase. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22operate%20on%20a%20schedule%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: I can't really get what "on" means there. Does it mean that someone makes people to operate for a few seconds of the time that you given to make a speech?

Comment: I think it's a somewhat "quirky" usage, but I did find a handful of written instances of [*operate on your time.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22operate+on+your+time%22) It's pretty much the same as [*to dance to someone's tune*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-dance-to-someones-tune) - but in OP's exact context that might not *quite* work, since the expectant audience probably aren't moving at all (they're just sitting and waiting, patiently or otherwise). Another related usage is *to have [the audience] **at one's beck and call**.*

Comment: Dymtro, consider "The train runs **on** schedule". **on** = according to.   Or *I can help her move into a new apartment, but we will have to do it **on** my time*.  That is, "according to what fits with my own schedule".